# Querying from a view takes minutes in SSMS, but times out in Excel. How to diagnose?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, powerquery

I have a set of queries against views that run just fine in SSMS. They completed in SSMS in, at most, 3 minutes and not all that much longer in Excel (via Power Query). I recently added some more `PARTITION BYs` to one of the views on which they depend and now, perhaps coincidentally, they're now not much slower in SSMS but they now take so long to query in Excel that it times out.

The query is far too big to post here. My question is only this: How do I begin to diagnose such issues and find the cause of this huge disparity?

Comment: The scope of this question is probably too wide for SO, but I don't want to leave you high and dry on it. Execute your query in SSMS with the "Show Actual Execution Plan" option activated and view the resulting plan. You'll likely see a large number of "Index Scans", "Key Lookups", and "Sorts" as well as multiple warnings that should point you toward more specific issues in your queries. I suspect that you are missing indexes on underlying tables (or even your views) that will dramatically improve your timings.

Comment: @paneerakbari Already tried doing that to look for indexes. I've not read through the execution plan, but no indexes were recommended.

Comment: try maintain the query folding

Comment: @Rosetta I'm afraid that I'm totally unfamiliar with that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding

Comment: you may also want to look at buffering certain steps in the query, M language is built in such way that certain SQL script, although folded, is "lazy" and thus very slow, buffering certain steps overcome the problem

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/multiple-queries

Comment: @Rosetta Virtually all of it is in SQL Server. It's little more than SELECT * FROM [MY_FINAL_VIEW].

Comment: [This addresses folding SQL](https://wisedatadecisions.com/2021/07/20/query-folding-with-value-nativequery/) and might help.

Comment: In my head, minutes is a long time for a query.   Perhaps this may help.   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/95eeb415-c71e-4df9-955c-f2805c365906/the-connection-timeout-was-exceeded?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Comment: @MarcPincince I've tried not writing any Power Query at all and just telling Excel to pull the data from the relevant view in SQL Server. I get the same issue.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti That's just telling me how to set the timeout parameters, right? The problem isn't that the query times out, it's that it takes much longer than it should.

Comment: @J.Mini if you haven't resolved this yet, it's a good idea to include an execution plan to let us know what we're dealing with: Run the query in SSMS with "Actual Execution plan" (Ctrl+m), right click the plan and open the XML. Copy/Paste that to brentozar.com/pastetheplan and put the link in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour - "fast in SSMS, slow in application" can be caused by a feature of SQL Server called [Parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/).

> SQL Server uses a process called parameter sniffing when it executes
> stored procedures that have parameters. When the
> procedure is compiled or recompiled, the value passed into the
> parameter is evaluated and used to create an execution plan. That
> value is then stored with the execution plan in the plan cache. On
> subsequent executions, that same value – and same plan – is used.

This process works for any query, not just stored procedures. Also, the engine "sniffs" not just values of parameters, but cardinality estimates (how many rows the tables have). This means that my suggestion below may help even if your query does not have parameters.

The article [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) by Erland Sommarskog explains this and other related areas in much more details. I would highly recommend reading it regardless of whether my suggestion below helps you or not.

I hope you use SQL Server 2008 or later. To start with, simply try to add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to your query, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [MY_FINAL_VIEW] 
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
;
```